# Check correlation between dichotomous and continuous variable

Tags: correlation, binary-data, continuous-data

I have a model in which I suspect two variables to may be related. However, one is a binary/dichotomous variable, while the other is a continous variable. What approach should be used to check if my statement has any merit or not? The Point-Biserial Correlation test, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, point-biserial correlation is an option. You can also run a t-test and compare means between the two levels of your binary variable. These two approaches actually are algebraically identical ([Ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient)).